# Функции под классами

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ошибка с функцией `license_test`, когда я её запускаю выдаётся ошибка

> TypeError: license_test() missing 1 required positional argument:
>   'identificator'

но как я же передал `DUCK43`

```
from pymongo import *
class eao():
    client = MongoClient('mongodb+srv://easyantiobman:easyantiobman@cluster0-qsvdn.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority')
    db = client['easyantiobman']
    collection = db['easyantiobman']
    def license_test(self, identificator):
        a=self.collection.find_one({'_id':identificator})
        print(a['license'])
        pass

jas = eao
jas.license_test('DUCK43')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передал, да не туда. Объекты класса создаются со скобками:

```
jas = eao()
```